# How to override the user edit page using Panels?

Tags: 7, panels, users

I am trying to override the user edit page in Drupal7 using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels). I checked the selection rule as user being edited are one of authenticated and administrator.

However, when I try to add a context to it and select the context User being edited, it asks me:

> Enter the name or UID of a node
>
> (A user edit form)

What do I write in here, any suggestions? Am I on the correct track or do I have to add any other context or relationship as well?

I also tried giving different path and ID but then I get some kind of ajax error.

Ps: Below is my screen shot, what do I enter in the first field?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user_edit panel default context is the current edited user. Why do you need to add an additional context with a user?

If you need to access to user values you can use the default context. For example you can use %user:uid in order to load the user ID which is being edited.

Comment: i thought so...but then i am not getting username, password and picture as forms to be edited, i am just being able to display them...on the other hand, my custom fields which i added in account settings are coming under forms and i am able to edit them